# button html element with javascript works only once

Tags: jquery

im quite new to javascript, and jquery.

i am currently making a site, in which i have a combobox along side a button that uses the .load() funcion to pass on the value selected on the combobox while loading and populating a form.

problem being, the button works, but only once...
how can i make this button work without having to reload the page?

btw: i am using widgets from kendo.

```
    <?php
// query all clients data
$query = 'SELECT
*
FROM
clientes
ORDER BY
clie_razonsocial';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$searchbox1 .=  '"'. $row['clie_razonsocial'] . '"' . ',' ;
$searchbox1 .=  '"'. $row['clie_telefono1'] . '"' . ',' ;
$searchbox1 .=  '"'. $row['clie_cuilcuit'] . '"' . ',' ;
}
$searchbox1=substr($searchbox1, 0, strlen($searchbox1)-1);
?>

<td> <input name="seleccionCliente1" id="seleccionCliente1" /></td>

<script> 

var data =[<?php echo $searchbox1; ?>];


$("#seleccionCliente1").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data,
    change: function(){
    var autocomplete = $("#seleccionCliente1").data("kendoAutoComplete");
    //window.location = "/mensajeria/mensajeriamain.php?value="+ autocomplete.value();  
    }
    });

</script>

<button id="Fill" class="k-button">Fill Form</button><script type="text/javascript">

  $("button").click(function(){

  var autocomplete = $("#seleccionCliente1").data("kendoAutoComplete");

  var data= autocomplete.value();
  alert(data);
    $("div1").load('/mensajeria/agregarViajes.php', {value:data});
  });

</script>

<div1> </div1>
```

edit: i have found a work around to the problem.
the fact seems to be that the .load function replaces the div element in which it will load the remote page, and breaks out the javascript function holding it as well. from document to element.

the work around is dirty and not practical given it relies on plainly generating the html form with the .html() jquery function. if anyone else knows how to tidy this up i would greatly appreciate it because this isnt very useful when programming.

```
<button id="Fill" class="k-button">Fill Form</button><script type="text/javascript">

$('#Fill').live('click', function(){

  var autocomplete = $("#seleccionCliente1").data("kendoAutoComplete");

  var data= autocomplete.value();



  alert(data);

  if(document.getElementById('Form') == null){alert('es nulo');
  $('div1').html('<p1 id="Form"></p1>');
  }

  $('div1').html('<p1 id="Form"><h2>Formulario Agregar Viajes</h2><form id="testform" action="verifico.php?action=viaje" method="post"><table><tr><th>Razon Social:</th><th>Telefono:</th><th>Interno:</th></tr><tr><td> <input name="seleccionCliente2" id="seleccionCliente2" /></td><td> <input type="int" name="f_Telefono" id="f_Telefono" /></td><td> <input type="int" name="c_Interno"/></td>   </tr><tr>   <th> CUIT/CUIL </th>    <th> EMAIL </th>    <th> Caso Cerrado </th> </tr><tr><td> <input type="text" name="CUIT/CUIL" /></td><td> <input type="text" name="E-mail" id="E_email" /></td><td> <input type="checkbox" name="cerrado" /> </td>  </tr><tr>   <th>Direccion Principal:</th>   <th>Razon Social</th>   </tr>   <tr>    <td> <input type="text" name="Direccion_Principal" /></td>  </tr></table><table><th> NOTAS: </th><td> <textarea name="Notas" rows="5" cols="50"> </textarea> </td></table><input type="submit" name="Procesar" value="Procesar"></form></html><em>You bet!</em></p1>');

  //$('p1').load('/mensajeria/agregarViajes.php', {value:data});
  });


</script>

<div1> </div1>
```

so i ended up loading the whole form page in a single .html line , pretty dirty, but now the button works.  thanks to foamdino for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to be doing:

```
$("#Fill").click(function() {
    formin()
});
```

In your code you are not actually running the function.

Comment: hey Sanketh, thanks for looking at it, however it does not solve the problem, i have modified the previous version to a simpler function, but the issue remains. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case where the first time the page is loaded the event handler is correctly bound to the element, but after the load is called the element is replaced and the event handler is no longer bound.

I think there is documentation at the jquery site that deals with this issue, but I cannot find it - this site does give a good rundown of the different jquery ajax issues:
http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Comment: hey foamdino, that page reads good, though i am having understanding it.

Comment: hey foamdino, that page reads good, though i am having understanding it. according to the DOM tree in the page, the document element is root node to all other elements, does this mean that a> span> or p> are all html elements generated by $(document)? 
i just tried this, still works only once:

    <script type="text/javascript">
 
    $('button').live('click', function(){
    var autocomplete =    $("#seleccionCliente1").data("kendoAutoComplete");      
    var data= autocomplete.value();
    alert(data);
    $("div1").load('/mensajeria/agregarViajes.php', {value:data});
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a get?  Load is a more simple get, but this way you don't have to chain off an element and you can still use the html() method.

```
$.get("/mensajeria/agregarViajes.php")
     .success(function (data) {
         //Add result to DOM
         $(".div1").html(data);
     })
     .error(function (result) {
          alert("TODO: Better Error Handling");
     });
```

Comment: i am requesting a full page be displayed through button activation without reloading a php page, through javascript/jquery, is $.get() used for data specific purpose?

Comment: You can load full content that way.  .get will get whatever you want.